# Retrieve data from database with id value

Tags: php, database

This is a link from another php file which directs to update.php file. I got the id of the link from this link. Now i want to use that id to retrieve data from database how can i do that?

```
echo '<a href="update.php?id= "'.$row['id'].'">Modify</a>';
```

Now This is my update.php file

```
echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\">\n"; 
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$id= $_GET['id'];
$query  = "SELECT * FROM promoter where id=$id ";// this code is not retrieving value from database
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   $user_id=$row['user_id'];
$full_name=$row['full_name'];
$qualification=$row['qualification'];
$locality=$row['locality'];
$description=$row['description'];
}

echo "<td>User Id</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\" value=\"$user_id\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Full Name</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"full_name\" value=\"    $full_name\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Qualification</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"qualification\" value=\" $qualification\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Locality</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"locality\" value=\" $locality\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<td>Description</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"description\"     value=\" $description\"></td>\n"; 
echo "</tr>\n";

echo "</form>\n";
```

Now I want to retrieve the data from data base having id= the id value that i have got from the link so that i can display the value according to id

Comment: please describe what is not working. are you getting an error?

Comment: I am not able to display the value from database in the table since the where id=$id is not providing value to the query

Comment: please  put all the `echo ' ' ;`  after the while loop,please place inside the  while  loop.

Comment: `var_dump($query)` might help. You have some issues with your db access (untested user input, deprecated functions) but start by checking whether `$query` is what you want, then move on to fix the rest.

Comment: when i put where id=1 or 2 or some value i am able to display the data in the table but i want to display value with the link id number

Comment: Can we retrieve data from database with id= the value of link id that we have?

Comment: Can you clarify what is actually wrong? What is the querystring in the url? What is the value of `$id`? What is the value of `$query`?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your SELECT statement - don't put this live!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your solution working code is.

```
  echo '<a href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Modify</a>';
```

Replace above code with this line. Actually your mistake is you have completed **"** before URL completed so your dynamically passed value is not consider as parameter i just remove that double (`"`). hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you check id retrieve to the update.php check that.

```
echo $id;
```

if that is displayed then you have to check any values are retrieve from the db with your SQL query.

```
print_r($result);
```

After replacing your code with below

```
echo "<form>\n"; 
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$id= $_GET['id'];
$query  = "SELECT * FROM promoter WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $user_id=$row['user_id'];
    $full_name=$row['full_name'];
    $qualification=$row['qualification'];
    $locality=$row['locality'];
    $description=$row['description'];

    echo "<td>User Id</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"user_id\" value=\"$user_id\"></td>\n"; 
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<td>Full Name</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"full_name\" value=\"    $full_name\"></td>\n"; 
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<td>Qualification</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"qualification\" value=\" $qualification\"></td>\n"; 
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<td>Locality</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"locality\" value=\" $locality\"></td>\n"; 
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<td>Description</td><td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"description\"     value=\" $description\"></td>\n"; 
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "</form>\n"; 
}
```

Comment: what have you changed?

Comment: The `while` is probably misused in the OP's code - make this an `if` instead, and then move all the HTML code inside the `if` block. In order words, consider the case of when a row does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However you don't need an additional block, just do `if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ... set vars ... html ... }`.

Comment: Thanks For the Info. Changed. @halfer

Comment: I've made a suggested edit - there is no need for the `while` at all. You can only call `mysql_fetch_array` once anyway, since it consumes a row every time you call it - and there is a maximum of one row to read.

Comment: Oh Yeh ! You are right. i am  not think about that. @halfer